# gulp serve command open a browser with error: "This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response"

Tags: node.js, ssl, sharepoint, gulp, spfx

I can't able to check out the SharePoint Frameworks Web Part in my browser as it says "This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response" ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. I have tried every possible solution for this while surfing like: Computer’s Date And Time Is Correct, Temporarily Disabled Firewall and Antivirus Software, Disable Chrome QUIC Protocol, Cleared SSL state, Changed Internet Security And Privacy Level to medium & low , Disabled Internet Browser Extensions (running in Incognito mode). Still not worked. Any Help on this will be appreciated.

[image]
[image: Error I got]

Comment: what is your node.js version ?

Comment: Running the command node -v it says v9.2.0 (x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only NodeJs v6 is supported by SPFx.

Please uninstall your current Node and install `v6.11.5`. Also, ensure that you have installed `npm` version 3.

Reference - [Set up your SharePoint client-side web part development environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Comment: Awesome, could you please mark it as answer :)  Its just checking the checkmark !

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the screenshot on you answer, it says that the Node Version is : v8.9.1

[image]

While working with SPFx on Node.js v8 you have to run gulp serve as:

`NODE_NO_HTTP2=1 gulp serve`

Try to use it. Hope it works for you.

Also refer this thread : https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1002

Comment: I have changed the version to 9.2.0 today's morning Rohit and got the same error. So i came to know that my problem is not the version I use, its about running it by opening the browser
and display the client web part by creating a Nodebased
HTTPS server at 'localhost:4321'. Any other way to overcome it?